# ClassCastException: JSONArray cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]

Tags: java, android, arrays, classcastexception

Hi I am trying to display the error messages stored in the following JSONObject obj

```
{"errors":["nickname is already taken,","email is already taken"]}
```

This is my implementation:

```
TextView errorMsg;
errorMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.register_error);
String[] errorArray = (String[])obj.get("errors");                                       
errorMsg.setText(errorArray[0]);                                                         
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorArray[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

However when trying to run the code, I get a ClassCastException

[image]

Can anyone explain to me the issue and how I can resolve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "errors" array in your example isn't a String array (String[]), it's a JSONArray.

Instead, do

```
JSONArray errorArray = obj.getJSONArray("errors");
```

then,

```
errorMsg.setText(errorArray.getString(0));                                                         
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorArray.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: A small note for someone stumbling into this like me. JSONArray extends ArrayList. So if you want you can just do "ArrayList<String> items = obj.getJSONArray("errors"); String[] arr = items.toArray()"

Answer (score 2):

The 'erros' array is not `String` array. So get value in `JSONArray`
do this.

```
JSONArray errorArray = obj.getJSONArray("errors");
```

you can convert it.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    list.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it's an `JsonArray` and not an `String array` so use library like [simple-json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1) from **google** and parse using below code:

```
       JSONArray erroeArray= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("errors");
        Iterator<String> iterator = erroeArray.iterator();
          while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            //yourcode here
          }
```